# Equivalent of openvswitch-brcompat on Fedora/RHEL/CentOS

Tags: fedora, rhel

On Debian & Ubuntu, the openvswitch-brcompat package will install Open vSwitch bridge compatibility support.

Is there an equivalent package on Fedora-based distros like RHEL and CentOS?

Comment: IIRC the brcompat has been removed from Open vSwitch in recent versions. Recent from a Debian perspective, so it can be expected other distros haven't had it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but on my Fedora 19 system ...

```
# yum search all vswitch
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, ps, refresh-packagekit, verify
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.symnds.com
 * livna: rpm.livna.org
 * rpmfusion-free: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.symnds.com
=========================== Matched: vswitch =============================
openvswitch.i686 : Open vSwitch daemon/database/utilities
openvswitch-controller.i686 : Open vSwitch OpenFlow controller
openvswitch-test.noarch : Open vSwitch testing utilities
python-openvswitch.noarch : Open vSwitch python bindings
openstack-quantum-openvswitch.noarch : Quantum openvswitch plugin
ovsdbmonitor.noarch : Open vSwitch graphical monitoring tool

# yum info openvswitch
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, ps, refresh-packagekit, verify
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.symnds.com
 * livna: rpm.livna.org
 * rpmfusion-free: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.symnds.com
Available Packages
Name        : openvswitch
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.10.0
Release     : 7.fc19
Size        : 1.4 M
Repo        : updates/19/i386
Summary     : Open vSwitch daemon/database/utilities
URL         : http://openvswitch.org
License     : ASL 2.0 and LGPLv2+ and SISSL
Description : Open vSwitch provides standard network bridging functions and
            : support for the OpenFlow protocol for remote per-flow control of
            : traffic.
```